# VBA Userform Path/File Access Error - Error 75

Tags: ms-access, vba, runtime-error, userform

Excel 2013 32bit / Access 2013 32bit / Win 7 64bit

Progress Bar Code:

```
Sub progress(pctCompl As Single)
If pctCompl = 100 Then
    Unload ProgressBar
    Exit Sub
End If
ProgressBar.Text.Caption = pctCompl & "% Completed"
ProgressBar.Bar.Width = pctCompl * 2

DoEvents

End Sub
```

Launcher Coder:

```
Sub LaunchPBUF()
ProgressBar.Show '<-- Error Location
End Sub
```

What I've done:

1. Exported Userform from Excel & Imported into Access
2. Noticed .frx file w/ .frm import, couldn't insure the .frx was being imported
3. Deleted Userform from Access & Recreated in Access
4. Did so by following the instructions here

   - right-click "Tools" and customizing the tool bar to have the add userform command
   - Userform Design: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/progress-indicator.html

[image: Path/File Access Error]

[image: Run-Time Error 75]

Comment: I don't quite understand - have you created a regular Access form, or a "Userform" which normally doesn't exist in Access?

Comment: a userform, I created it two ways - first by importing it from Excel and secondly by actually creating it in Access as described in the link above in the original question.

Comment: I see. I strongly recommend using a "native" Access form, hardly anybody uses Userforms in Access. Or use [SysCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193809.aspx) to create a progress bar without a form.

Comment: That'll work Andre, throw it up as an answer and I'll select it.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using a "native" Access form, hardly anybody uses Userforms in Access.

Or use [SysCmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193809.aspx) to create a progress bar without a form.